# Overloading insertion operator for std::array

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to overload the insertion (`<<`) operator to output elements of an `std::array`. The following yields a compilation error:

```cpp
// overload operator<< to display array objects of any type T and size N
template<typename T, int N>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &Output, const std::array<T,N> &Arr) {
    for (const auto &Element: Arr)
        Output << Element << " ";
    return Output;
}
```

But the following works just fine (if I apply it to an array of, say, 5 elements):

```cpp
// overload operator<< to display array objects of any type T and size 5
template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &Output, const std::array<T,5> &Arr) {
    for (const auto &Element: Arr)
        Output << Element << " ";
    return Output;
}
```

I'm aware that arrays need to know their size `N` at compile time, but doesn't the template provide just that?

The error happens when I try, for instance, the following:

```cpp
std::array<int,5> MyArr {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::cout << "MyArr = " << MyArr;
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  What is the code that is causing the error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to [edit] your questions, and how to create a [mre].

Comment: Your question is not exactly clear. What is the problem you are facing with the above code samples?

Comment: Note that neither of your code snippets will compile: `output` != `Output`.

Comment: @AdrianMole I wrote `Output`, never wrote `output`. You can name your variables whatever you'd like... Since I've started to work with the Unreal Engine I'm following their Pascal convention.

Comment: @MarioGutierrez "*I wrote `Output`, never wrote `output`*" - Are you sure? Look again at the code you posted: `std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &Output, ...) { ... return output; }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau oops yeah I caught that now. However, I didn't have this issue on my source code, just on this post. Anyhow, your comment about `size_t` vs `int` saved the day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd template argument of `std::array` is a `size_t`, not an `int`.

Also, `return output;` needs to be `return Output;` as  C++ is case-sensitive.

```
// overload operator<< to display array objects of any type T and size N
template<typename T, size_t N>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &Output, const std::array<T,N> &Arr) {
    for (const auto &Element: Arr)
        Output << Element << " ";
    return Output;
}
```